# TS error Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'state' does not exist in type 'Partial<Path>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, react-router

I'm trying to pass props through react router link. Its basically all the user props.
This is my code thats getting the error where `state: {...employee}` is highlighted. I'm really noob when it comes to typescript, trying to get better at it but I'm running into all sorts of problems. When i try to add anything to the state, i still get the same error.

```
 <Link to={{ pathname: `/edit-employee/${id}`, state: {...employee} }}>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This code would be fine in react-router 5, but you appear to be using react-router 6. In version 6, they split state into its own prop, so you would now do:

```
<Link to={`/edit-employee/${id}`} state={{...employee}}>
```

Comment: Hey Nicholas i have a separate question regarding typescript. I'm passing an async function as props but I'm having a hard time setting the interface.

Comment: I tried this code here ```interface Props { uploadImage: Promise<string> }``` But when i call the uploadImage function I'm getting this ts error ```Type 'Promise<string>' has no call signatures.```

Comment: if uploadImage is a function that returns a promise, then it's type should be `uploadImage: () => Promise<string>`